# dynamic associative array post name

Tags: php, html, post

I have a registration form for a homeowner's associated. A home owner could actually own multiple lots, which needs to be registered. I do this by allowing the user to click a button that adds text fields to the form to allow for additional data. There is no limit to how many additional lots that can be registered. My problem is how do I manage the post names? the address, city, state, and zipcode all need to be grouped together. Basically, how can I get this result:

```
$_POST = array(
    'mainAddress' => array(
        'address' => '',
        'city' => '',
        'state' => '',
        'zipcode' => ''
    )
    'additionalAddresses' => array(
        array(
            'address' => '',
            'city' => '',
            'state' => '',
            'zipcode' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'address' => '',
            'city' => '',
            'state' => '',
            'zipcode' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'address' => '',
            'city' => '',
            'state' => '',
            'zipcode' => ''
        )
    )
);
```

is this even possible? if not, what can I do to accept additional addresses?

Comment: dont use an "additional address" rather make addresses 1:n values

Comment: ? example please? not sure I understand

Comment: sorry re-read the question - seed the post results as a delimited value so instead of, "additonavalue=somevalue&addtionalvalue=somevalue" - process it as a concat'd : "additionalAddresses=<address1>%2C<adress2>%2C<address>%2C<etc..>   you will just need to adjust your $_POST variable store to reflect the additional values  AND of course parse said post values on consumption. Don't get hung up on the "POST" aspect - think in terms of GET

Comment: ok, so there is no way to do this with just the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
    <form>
Address 1
    <input name="address[]" value="">
    <input name="zip[]" value="">
    <input name="city[]" value="">
    <input name="state[]" value="">

Address 2
    <input name="address[]" value="">
    <input name="zip[]" value="">
    <input name="city[]" value="">
    <input name="state[]" value="">

Address 3
    <input name="address[]" value="">
    <input name="zip[]" value="">
    <input name="city[]" value="">
    <input name="state[]" value="">
    </form>
```

PHP Code :

```
$new_address_array = array();
foreach($_POST['address'] as $k=>$v){
$temparray['address'] = $v;
$temparray['city'] = $_POST['city'][$k]; 
$temparray['state'] = $_POST['state'][$k]; 
$temparray['zip'] = $_POST['zip'][$k]; 
$new_address_array[] = $temparray;
}

$final['addtional_address']=$new_address_array;

print_r($final);
```

Comment: Jay with the freebees tonight!

Comment: ok, so you can guarantee me that each of the fields index's will match up every time?

Comment: Yups it must! I have experience!

Comment: what happens if not all four are filled out for each one?

Comment: You will find blank in POST array.

Comment: that worked! I wanted to do this before, but i just couldn't imagine it working. guess I should have tried it anyway